# How to store a secretKey in database postgresql and retrieve it

Tags: java, postgresql, encryption, aes, secret-key

I tried convert it to byte[] and store it on a bytea but it didn't work, i don't receive the same secretkey that i stored. Using type String didn't work as well

if you're interested in more details, my application is to crypt and decrypt pictures using AES and these are methods to crypt and decrypt

```
public void crypt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException{

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKey secKey = keyGen.generateKey();
    byte[] encoded = secKey.getEncoded();
    this.setCodeCrypt(encoded);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);

    String cleartextFile = this.lien;
    String ciphertextFile = "crypted img.jpg";

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cleartextFile);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ciphertextFile);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

    int i;
    while ((i = fis.read()) != -1) {
        cos.write(i);
    }
    cos.close();
}

    // Decrypt
public void decrypt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException{
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/papiersadmin";
        String user = "postgres";
        String passwd = "postgresql";
        java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,passwd);
        Statement state = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        // loading a picture knowing its path (lien)

        ResultSet result = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM image WHERE lien = '"+this.lien+"'");
        while(result.next()){
        setCodeCrypt(result.getObject(6).toString().getBytes());}
        state.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(codeCrypt, 0, codeCrypt.length, "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey);

    String cleartextFile = "decrypted img.jpg";
    String ciphertextFile = this.lien;

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ciphertextFile);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cleartextFile);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

    int i;
    while ((i = fis.read()) != -1) {
        cos.write(i);
    }
    cos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a `byte[]` to a String using `toString()` and then calling `getBytes()` will not do anything useful.  I would suggest starting with `ResultSet.getBytes()`.

Comment: i tried this test

 while(result.next()){
  //there is only one result on the database
  setCodeCrypt(result.getBytes(6));}
  System.out.println(result.getBytes(6)+" "+codeCrypt+"  "+result.getBytes(6));
   System.out.println(result.getObject(6).toString().getBytes());
  state.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

and this is what i get 

[B@1b32627   [B@8dcd5d  [B@1a5af9f
[B@15e538e


i don't get it :/

Comment: java arrays have a useless toString method.  use `Arrays.toString` util method instead.

Comment: how is that ? what should i change ?

Comment: did you look at the method i mentioned, in `java.util.Arrays`?

Comment: now everything is logic, i receive the same answers, i still have some problems but you helped me solve this one, thanks man